# For no positive integer $n$ can both $n+3$ and $n^2 + 3n + 3$ be perfect cubes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question is a competition-math related problem.

Show that for no positive integer $n$ can both $n+3$ and $n^2 + 3n + 3$ be perfect cubes.

Is there a way to solve the above problem without induction?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the question?  You just wrote $n^2+3n+$...looks incomplete.

Comment: Sorry, added the three at the end.

Comment: Please include a full statement of the problem in the body of the Question.  Trying to make the title alone carry the burden of problem statement makes a Reader's task of understanding difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that both of them are perfect cubes. Then their product will be a perfect cube as well.
The product will be $$n^3 + 6n^2 + 12 n + 9$$ But, this differs from $(n+2)^3$ by only one unit, which is not possible. Contradiction!
Hence it is not possible

Comment: Note that the pair of cubes $0,1$ (resp. $-1,0$) differ by one (and these are the only such cases), but these correspond to $n=-2$ (resp. $n=-3$).  So the claim concerning "no positive integer $n$" is established.

Comment: Yup. I should be less careless and explicitly state these cases! Thanks for the addition