# Can $n^2+3n+3$ be a perfect cube?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Can $n^2+3n+3$ be a perfect cube?

I think the answer is no. My proof: Let $b^3 = n^2 +3n + 3$. Then $nb^3 + 1 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 = (n+1)^3$.
So I just need to show that
$$ (n+1)^3 = nb^3 + 1$$
has no solutions. This seems to be true, but I have trouble proving it.

Can anyone help me prove or disprove this?

**Edit** As pointed out by WhatsUp in his answer, if you use elliptic curves you can compute that the only integral solution to the curve $y^2 + 3y = x^3 - 3$ is $n=17$. So with the additional condition that $n > 17$, $n^2 + 3n + 3$ is not a cube.

Comment: Perhaps you have confused it with [this homework question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170420/for-no-positive-integer-n-can-both-n3-and-n2-3n-3-be-perfect-cubes)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually I was trying to do that question. And I came across this line of thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can.

$17^2+3\times17+3=7^3$.

Answer (score 3):

This is an elliptic curve.

There might be elementary solutions, but the following sage code solves it in no time.

Paste the following in [this page](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and click "Evaluate".

```
E = EllipticCurve([0, 0, 3, 0, -3])
print(E.integral_points())
```

We see that there are two integral solutions $(b, n)$: $(1, -1)$ and $(7, 17)$.

By the symmetry $n \leftrightarrow -3 - n$, we get the other two: $(1, -2)$ and $(7, -20)$.

Comment: Woah - Thats a really nice insight! Are those two integral solutions the only integral solutions? I.e. if I were to add an additional caveat to the question that $n \ge 17$, then $n^2 + 3n + 3$ cannot be a cube?

Comment: These are the only integral solutions, as Sage is able to compute it exactly. Otherwise the output will probably tell you that the Mordell-Weil rank cannot be determined.

Comment: Thats awesome, I will add it as an edit to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Could I clarify something: The elliptic curve you are using is $y^2 + 3y = x^3 - 3$ right? I'm a bit confused what the tuple $[0,0,3,0,-3]$ represents.

Comment: Or in one line:

 `EllipticCurve([0, 0, 3, -3]).integral_points(both_signs=True)`

The given curve has rank $1$, and $P=(1, -1)$ is a generator. $2P$ is $(7,-20)$. $3P$ is $(73/6^2, 271/6^3)$ and so on.

Comment: @eatfood The command `EllipticCurve([a1, a2, a3, a4, a6])` creates an elliptic curve defined by the equation $y^2 + a_1 xy + a_3 y = x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_4 x + a_6$.

Comment: @eatfood The general form of an elliptic curve is 

$$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6\ .$$

And the coefficients are pasted in the list in the order. The index notation is not "missing the five", but it is rather done to respect the homogenity assuming $x$ had weight $2$ and $y$ weight $3$, so that the equation reads as a homogeneous equation of degree six. (And $a_k$ is considered to have weight $k$.)

Comment: Understood, thank you!